# Querying docker server in parallel raises connection error - python

Tags: python, docker, python-requests, osrm

In Python3, I am using `get.requests()` in a parallel loop to query a server that I have running in a docker container (specifically an [OSRM server](https://hub.docker.com/r/osrm/osrm-backend/)).

I get this error after it successfully queries a few:
`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))`

I think the Docker container has a limit on the number of queries at a time or from a single IP, but I don't know how to fix it. I'm assuming it's in the Docker settings.

I initiate the docker container using: `docker run --name osrm-nc -t -i -p 6002:5000 -v /homedirs/tml62/osm:/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm mld /data/north-carolina-latest.osrm`, so noteably, I'm assigning the [ports](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-54-fixing-connection-reset-by-peer-or-similar-errors)

I've set the retries so it can repeat and that sometimes fixes it, but it causes delays and sometimes will still break.

Comment: have you run top on the server? Seriously doubt it's Docker.

Comment: Yeah, but there are no other processes happening. I'm the only one using the machine. (@Neil I assume you mean `top` on the machine, or do you mean within the Docker container?)

Comment: I think it is more likely an issue with your application code. Do you see the same or different behavior if you run it *outside* of a container?

Comment: @larsks you're suggesting creating the OSRM server outside of a docker container? 

Comment: I am suggesting that if you have a theory that Docker is the problem, produce some data that demonstrates that fact so that we have solid data to work with.

Comment: ha, thanks. but it seems you may be right and this could be an issue with the osrm server and querying using http rather than node-bindings. which i will investigate and answer/update the question as required